# Zoom a datagrid centered

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, zooming

I have to write an application which is able to zoom in and out two different layers at the same time.

The background layer contains an image which is always centered during zooming. The second layer is based, however, on the upper edge of the parent container.

Here is my XAML-Code:

```
<ScrollViewer Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="DZBackgroundImage" Source="{Binding DZGridBackground}" Stretch="None" />
        <DataGrid ColumnWidth="7" MinColumnWidth="7" RowHeight="15" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
            Visibility="{Binding GridIsVisible}" ItemsSource="{Binding DPGridCR}" Margin="5,50,70,0" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent"
            HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserResizeRows="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{Binding LineBrush}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{Binding LineBrush}">

            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <ViewModel:IgnoreMouseWheelBehavior />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

            <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#325EB226" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#325EB226" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.CellStyle>

            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Feld hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/field.png" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFunctionCommand}" Header="Funktion hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/function.png" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Aktuelle Felddefinition entfernen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/remove_field.png" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Header="Ausschneiden" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Ausschneiden_16x16.png" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Header="Kopieren" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Kopieren_16x16.png" />
                    <MenuItem Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" Header="Einfügen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Einfuegen_16x16.png" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

        </DataGrid>

        <Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomFactor}" />
        </Grid.LayoutTransform>
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I get the values for the ZoomFactor binding from my view-model.

My goal is to zoom the two layers simultaneously and overlapped.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Here comes the whole XAML-File.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.DZLeerformularGrid"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:ViewModel;assembly=ViewModel"
    xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:ViewModel.Behaviors;assembly=ViewModel"
    xmlns:Extension="clr-namespace:Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    x:Name="DZLeerformularGridControl">

    <ScrollViewer Behaviors:AdvancedZooming.KeepInCenter="true" Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Viewbox RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" Stretch="Uniform">
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="DZBackgroundImage" Source="{Binding DZGridBackground}" Stretch="None" />
                <DataGrid ColumnWidth="7" MinColumnWidth="7" RowHeight="15" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" CanUserAddRows="False"
            Visibility="{Binding GridIsVisible}" ItemsSource="{Binding DPGridCR}" Margin="5,50,70,0" Background="Transparent" RowBackground="Transparent"
            HeadersVisibility="None" SelectionUnit="Cell" CanUserResizeRows="False" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{Binding LineBrush}" VerticalGridLinesBrush="{Binding LineBrush}">

                    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Behaviors:IgnoreMouseWheelBehavior />
                    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#325EB226" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#325EB226" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>

                    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Feld hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/field.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding AddFunctionCommand}" Header="Funktion hinterlegen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/FI_Taschenmesser_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding RemoveFieldDefinitionCommand}" Header="Aktuelle Felddefinition entfernen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Designer/remove_field.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding CutCommand}" Header="Ausschneiden" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Ausschneiden_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" Header="Kopieren" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Kopieren_16x16.png" />
                            <MenuItem Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" Header="Einfügen" Icon="pack://application:,,,/Images/Zwischenablage/FI_Einfuegen_16x16.png" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>

                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>

            <Viewbox.RenderTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomFactor}" ScaleY="{Binding ZoomFactor}" />
            </Viewbox.RenderTransform>
        </Viewbox>

    </ScrollViewer>

</UserControl>
```

Following comes the C# code for my ViewModel:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Input;
using ViewModelBase;
using System.Windows;

namespace ViewModel
{
    public class DZLeerformularGridViewModel : ViewModelBase.ViewModelBase
    {
        #region Fields
        #region Command Fields
        private RelayCommand addFieldDefinition;
        private RelayCommand removeFieldDefinition;
        private RelayCommand addFunction;
        private RelayCommand cutCommand;
        private RelayCommand copyCommand;
        private RelayCommand pasteCommand;
        #endregion

        private string leerformularIsVisible;
        private string dzGridBackground;
        private string gridIsVisible;
        private SolidColorBrush lineBrush;
        private DataTable dpGridCR;
        private double zoomFactor;
        #endregion

        public DZLeerformularGridViewModel()
        {
            LineBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
        }

        #region Properties
        public string LeerformularIsVisible
        {
            get { return leerformularIsVisible; }
            set
            {
                if (leerformularIsVisible != value)
                {
                    leerformularIsVisible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("LeerformularIsVisible");
                }
            }
        }

        public string DZGridBackground
        {
            get { return dzGridBackground; }
            set
            {
                if (dzGridBackground != value)
                {
                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(value);
                    if (img.Height > img.Width)
                        generateColsAndRows(94, 70);    // DIN A4 Hochformat
                    else
                        generateColsAndRows(70, 94);    // DIN A4 Querformat

                    dzGridBackground = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DZGridBackground");
                }
            }
        }

        public string GridIsVisible
        {
            get { return gridIsVisible; }
            set
            {
                if (gridIsVisible != value)
                {
                    gridIsVisible = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("GridIsVisible");
                }
            }
        }

        public SolidColorBrush LineBrush
        {
            get { return lineBrush; }
            set
            {
                if (lineBrush != value)
                {
                    if (!value.Equals(Brushes.LightGray) || !value.Equals(Brushes.Gray) || ! value.Equals(Brushes.LightSlateGray) || !value.Equals(Brushes.SlateGray) ||
                    !value.Equals(Brushes.Black) || !value.Equals(Brushes.Red) || !value.Equals(Brushes.DarkGray))
                        lineBrush = Brushes.LightGray;
                    else
                        lineBrush = value;

                    OnPropertyChanged("LineBrush");
                }
            }
        }

        public DataTable DPGridCR
        {
            get { return dpGridCR; }
            set
            {
                if (dpGridCR != value)
                {
                    dpGridCR = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("DPGridCR");
                }
            }
        }

        public double ZoomFactor
        {
            get { return zoomFactor; }
            set
            {
                if (zoomFactor != value)
                {
                    zoomFactor = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("ZoomFactor");
                }
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Command Properties
        public ICommand AddFieldDefinitionCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (addFieldDefinition == null)
                    addFieldDefinition = new RelayCommand(p => ExecuteAddFieldDefinitionCommand());

                return addFieldDefinition;
            }
        }

        public ICommand RemoveFieldDefinitionCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (removeFieldDefinition == null)
                    removeFieldDefinition = new RelayCommand(p => ExecuteRemoveFieldDefinitionCommand());

                return removeFieldDefinition;
            }
        }

        public ICommand AddFunctionCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (addFunction == null)
                    addFunction = new RelayCommand(p => ExecuteAddFunctionCommand());

                return addFunction;
            }
        }

        public ICommand CutCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (cutCommand == null)
                    cutCommand = new RelayCommand(p => ExecuteCutCommand());

                return cutCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand CopyCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (copyCommand == null)
                    copyCommand = new RelayCommand(p => ExecuteCopyCommand());

                return copyCommand;
            }
        }

        public ICommand PasteCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (pasteCommand == null)
                    pasteCommand = new RelayCommand(p => ExecutePasteCommand());

                return pasteCommand;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Methods
        private void generateColsAndRows(int amountOfCols, int amountOfRows)
        {
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            List<DataColumn> cols = new List<DataColumn>();
            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfCols; i++)
            {
                DataColumn column = new DataColumn();
                column.ReadOnly = true;
                table.Columns.Add(column);
                cols.Add(column);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < amountOfRows; i++)
            {
                DataRow row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (DataColumn col in cols)
                    row[col] = " ";

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            DPGridCR = table;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Command Methods
        private void ExecuteAddFieldDefinitionCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add field definition");
        }

        private void ExecuteRemoveFieldDefinitionCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Remove field definition");
        }

        private void ExecuteAddFunctionCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Add function");
        }

        private void ExecuteCutCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Cut");
        }

        private void ExecuteCopyCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Copy");
        }

        private void ExecutePasteCommand()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Paste");
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

When I zoom in the image, no horizontal scrollbar appears. When I zoom out the image, the vertical scrollbar don't disappear. This effect is due to the use of `RenderTransform`. If I use `LayoutTransform` the `DataGrid` is bound to the upper edge of `Grid` or `ViewBox`. How could I solve this problem? In my opinion I require a combination of `LayoutTransform` and `RenderTransfrom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an attached behavior and attach the same to the scroll viewer. so the behavior will detect the change in size of the content and will maintain the content in center of the scroll viewer

here is a link to a similar question I answered earlier, you can find that behavior class in the answer

[Maintain scrollviewer's relative scrollbar offset when resizing child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24438470/maintain-scrollviewers-relative-scrollbar-offset-when-resizing-child/24526749#24526749)

so take the AdvancedZooming class from the answer in the link above and set the following property to the scroll viewer

```
<ScrollViewer Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              l:AdvancedZooming.KeepInCenter="True">
```

where l: refers to the namespace to your project. and that is all what you need to keep the content in center while zooming

**EDIT**

```
    <ScrollViewer Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  l:AdvancedZooming.KeepInCenter="True">
        <Viewbox>
            <Grid>
                <Image x:Name="DZBackgroundImage"
                       Source="{Binding DZGridBackground}" 
                       Stretch="None" />
                <DataGrid>
                 ...
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
            <Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ZoomFactor}"
                                ScaleY="{Binding ZoomFactor}" />
            </Viewbox.LayoutTransform>
        </Viewbox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

if you find the size of datagrid or image is too small or too big then try adjusting the width/height of grid, image or datagrid, viewbox will scale accordingly

Comment: Now I used your AdvancedZooming class but it doesn't work :(. Here is the code: `<ScrollViewer ViewModel:AdvancedZooming.KeepInCenter="true" Visibility="{Binding LeerformularIsVisible}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">` The image is always centered during zomming but the DataGrid is always zooming out to the upper edge of the parent Grid container. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: if `<Grid.LayoutTransform>` is not compulsory then try changing to `<Grid.RenderTransform>`.

Comment: Now I have a new problem :( `<Grid.RenderTransform>` doesn't affect the layout. This means that my ScrollViewer don't have scrollbars when I zoom in. Is there any solution that combine `<Grid.LayoutTransform>` and `<Grid.RenderTransform>`?

Comment: You're always welcome for the problems you have? you may give me the link to the posted question.

Comment: Now I edited my comment before. Do you think there are capabilities to solve my problem?

Comment: You can wrap your grid in a Viewbox and remove LayoutTransform from grid and apply to Viewbox.

Comment: Unfortunatelly there is no visible effect :( When I zoom in the image, the grid or viewbox container hold the same fixed size so I can't see the whole image with scrollbars. I am really buffled.

Comment: is it possible for you to post a sample of your application, may I try to adjust it for you.

Comment: Just I append an sample of my application to my question. I hope you could solve my problem :)

Comment: change `Viewbox.RenderTransform` to `Viewbox.LayoutTransform` also remove `RenderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5"` from Viewbox as it is not necessary anymore. see if that helps to achieve what you want.